# How to convert the PKCS12 openssl keystore to JKS keytstore with Java Keytool

Tags: java, openssl, keytool, jsse

Step i make key:

1. Create a Private Key

   ```
   openssl genrsa -des3 -out client.key 2048
   ```
2. Generate a Self-Signed Certificate

   ```
   openssl req -key client.key -new -x509 -days 365 -out client.crt -subj "/C=xxx/ST=yyy/L=zzz/O=aaa/CN=localhost"
   ```
3. Convert PEM to PKCS12

   ```
   openssl pkcs12 -export -in client.crt -inkey client.key -out client.p12
   ```
4. Convert the PKCS12 openssl keystore to JKS keytstore with Java Keytool

   ```
   keytool -importkeystore -destkeystore client_keystore.jks -deststoretype jks -deststorepass 1234567abc -srckeystore client.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -srcstorepass 1234567abc
   ```

I got error:

```
keytool error: java.io.IOException: failed to decrypt safe contents entry:
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
```

How to fix it, where was i wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
 -srcstorepass 1234567abc
```

You didn't specify a password when you created the PKCS#12 file. 
Where did you get this from?

You can do the entire process with the `keytool -genkey` option as a one-liner.

Comment: At step one: i created PKCS#12 file with password 1234567abc when command line required input

Comment: i can use keytool to create PKCS12 key file, but i can not create certificate, truststore from that file, can you post command line to create that file??

Comment: (a) `-genkey` creates both a key pair and a certificate. (b) You can use `keytool` to create a JKS file directly. There is no need to use PKCS#12 at all. (c) You can export the certficate from the keystore with `keytool`, and import it into a truststore.

Comment: Thanks for your response,
But i want to create certificate, truststore from PKCS12, can you give me cmd for that???

Comment: **Why** from PKCS#12? NB Step 1 doesn't create a PKCS#12 file. Step 3 does that.

Comment: Because i want to communicate other language through PKCS12 format

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that not all PCKS12 providers are exactly 100% compatible. I experienced the same error, and I was able to fix it by changing srcstoretype from 'PKCS12' to 'BCPKCS12'

This may help: https://cryptosense.com/bouncycastle-keystore-security/